# Use Category of products for Related Products

Tags: products-view, up-sells, cross-sells, related-products

I have a large number of products that share a list of about 52 related products, which I am displaying in a slider on the product page. I would like to take these 52 products and put them in their own category, then use that category to list those related products. It would save me TONS of time, especially down the road. Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where do you want to list them?

Comment: I want to list the products in the related products block

Comment: I just like to be able to select a certain category of products to display in the "Related Products"

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

- Add a custom product attribute say `related_product_cat_id`
- At product detail page use this attribute to load related products and display them.

If you are on EE, you may use `rule based product relations` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to set the category id of the products I need displayed in the related.phtml file?

Comment: Yep!, create a custom module to rewrite `catalog/product_list_related` block and override `_prepareData()` method